# basketball best scorer in one single game

Tags: basketball, records

Who is the best scorer in a single FIBA sanctioned basketball game in history? I've heard of a player in the Middle East who scored 110 points (with 33 3-pointers), is that true?

Answer (score 2):

The player you refer to is [Mohammad Akkari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammad_Akkari), who played for [Al Mouttahed Tripoli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Mouttahed_Tripoli) in Lebanon.  He scored 113 points, on 32 of 59 shooting from behind the arc, [in a game in a Lebanese league](https://www.espn.com/espn/story/_/id/7774255/mohammad-el-akkari-scores-113-points-fiba-asia-game) in 2012.  This was the first FIBA Asia hundred-point game.

From [wikipedia's list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_basketball_players_who_have_scored_100_points_in_a_single_game), the top several are children - U14 and U12 leagues mostly; most likely the highest by a professional player in a FIBA league (or equivalent; I'm not sure how far back FIBA goes) is [Erman Kunter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erman_Kunter), who scored 153 points in a [Turkish Super League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketball_Super_League) game in 1988: see this [very brief article about the game](https://web.archive.org/web/20190101011217/https://www.hoopsfix.com/2013/02/flashback-erman-kunters-153-point-world-record/) for more information.

[Anat Draigor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anat_Draigor) has the women's professional record at 136, though it's unclear what level the game was at (Israel's third level league, but I don't know enough about Israeli basketball to know if that translates to FIBA-level or not).  She does officially have the Guinness World Record (to the extent that matters), so it's apparently good enough for them at least.